# What is the difference between「市長」 and 「町長」?

Tags: kanji

So far, I have found these results:

- 市長{しちょう}: mayor
- 町長{ちょうちょう}: town headman; town mayor​

I would appreciate if someone could explain a more accurate difference, like everyday usage or any example in its context.

Comment: Depending on your Japanese reading ability, this may be helpful: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%82%E7%94%BA%E6%9D%91%E9%95%B7

Comment: This may also be useful (in English): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_addressing_system?oldformat=true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are totally different and, therefore, are ***never*** interchangeable.  What the head of a municipality is called solely depends on what that municipality itself is ***officially*** called.

According to [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%82%E7%94%BA%E6%9D%91), there are (as of 2016) 791 市, 744 町 and 183 村 in Japan.

If a municipality is called a 「市{し}」, its head is called 「市長{しちょう}」.  Likewise, 「町長{ちょうちょう}」 for a 「町{ちょう}」 and 「村長{そんちょう}」 for a 「村{むら}」.

Part of your confusion, I feel, may come from the linguistic fact that the word "town" is used quite loosely in English and so is the word 「町{まち}／街{まち}」 in Japanese.  Informally at least, those are often used to refer to an official "city".

Comment: I think it's more that the word "mayor" is used for municipalities of all sizes in English (especially the USA). ...We don't have many villages, but for towns and cities of all sizes, "mayor" is the word for the person at the top. It might be helpful for @Anurag Daolagajao to kind of ignore the word "mayor" and replace it with "leader" in his/her mind. You wouldn't say "town leader" or "village leader" when you meant "city leader". The image would be wrong.